# PrimeNG how can I change InputNumber typing direction?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm making a InputNumber Component for prices, but when I type in the numbers I want it to be right to left.

To make an example, let's say we have an input field showing "0.00", if I type key "1", it should show "0.01", if I type key "2", it should show "0.12", if I type key "6", it should show "1.26".

This way the user wouldn't need to type dots or click anything. How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this by creating directive, which detects changes & places the decimal separator at the good place.

i'll try to take some time to make an example if you need it.

**EDIT** :
Sorry for the late answer, i spent much time on it and i couldn't get it to work as good as expected, i encountered issues with change/keydown events (only firering once on inputNumbers...)

here's the best i've got, it's a base of work. Sorry i have no more time to search on it.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputnumber-demo-reji8s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

If you find a nice solution, please tell me, i'm interrested to know now :)

Comment: I'm new to this and have no idea how to start, It would be awesome if you could, Thank you! I'll be reading about this too